# Forms Authentication and User Timing out

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, session-variables, forms-authentication

The users of our website are complaining that they are timing out before 20 minutes , Below are my settings in web.config

The app pool Idle time out is also 20 Minutes

In the code where we login we have

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
string cookiestr;
HttpCookie ck;

tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, cust_id, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, "your custom data");
cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

In the Event Viewer we are getting this message

Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I see this is tagged with ASP.NET.  Is the server an ASP.NET server?  What programming language is your sample code?

Comment: I am using C# in my ASP.net Project

Comment: Where is your ASP.NET app running?  Is it running on a single IIS server?

Comment: Yes its running on single IIS server

Comment: Have you confirmed what your users are saying? Those aren't web.config settings are they?